# SQL Server Importing Excel data ..Confusion in selecting the Datatype in Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server

The question is regarding SQL Server 2010 Import and Export Wizard. I am in a strange situation.

I am trying to import Excel data into my database. One of the columns in Excel is `Part Number` which can have values like (418138031, A1801354B).

Now in `Import and Export Wizard` -> at `Edit mappings`..if I select `nvarchar` datatype for the column... only values like `A1801354B` are imported to my database. If I select `float` datatype only values like 418138031 are imported to my database.

What should I do if I want to retrieve both types of values i.e. 418138031, A1801354B.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Vanu

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** .... there's 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and soon be 2012 .... so which one is it??

Comment: Correct, but it is irrelevant. Problem is with the XL driver. Extremely frustrating thing. Its "guess" is often wrong, but it wont let you override it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the crappy excel (Jet) driver.  My recommendation would be to save the file as a csv and use the flat-file source instead.  Otherwise you have to wrestle with what the excel driver heuristics decide is the data type, and get the behavior you've described...